# ¿Como podria cargar un Template de forma rapida en Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xaml

Estoy intentando cargar un template de forma muy rápida en una Page, pero aun no he logrado resultados positivos, al momento de llamar a la Page esta tarda demasiado en mostrarse porque dentro de ella tiene incrustado el Template que esta muy cargado, he estado haciendo pruebas con un ControlTemplate pero aun sigue tardando, ¿cual seria la mejor de hacerlo?, les dejo un ejemplo de codigo xaml:

```
<AbsoluteLayout
    x:Class="Test.Templates.OrderTypeView"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="page">

</Code>...

<template:Order
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        IsVisible="{Binding OrderVisible}"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: La informacion que estas colocando es nula, porque decis que la vista te demora en cargar y solo agregas un elemento para mostrar, entonces es dificil de ayudar. Luego mientras mas componentes agregues, la vista tiene que hacer mas calculos para crear la pantalla. y por ultimo estas seguro que se demora la vista en cargar y no algo que te bloquea el procesador hasta que termina?

Comment: Habrá alguna forma de mejorar la carga del xaml?, ya sea algún Nuguet o cambiando la forma de cargar los datos de la vista, sugerencias?

Comment: La primera sugerencia es que coloques el codigo para verlo, y el codebehind tambien para ver que es lo que cargas y como lo haces. Cuanto tiempo toma la carga de la pantalla? y no podes segmentarla?